# Check whether a file's content is changed or not using Perl

Tags: perl

I want to create a script that can detect any changes made to a file. This is my starting code. Once I have detected a change, I will use `curl` to upload the new data into an online database.

This example below is just an online solution, other types of finding are welcome also.

What I require as pseudocode:

```
if (file content changed)
{
   #upload data 
   printf "file content changed, newest data uploaded";
}else{
   printf "file content no change"; 
   #do nothing
}
```

Actual code checking if file contents have changed:

```
use Digest::SHA qw(sha256_hex);
my $filename   = 'username/project/tota/datas/data.list';

my $old_mtime  = 0;
my $old_size   = 0;
my $old_digest = '';

while(1) {  # loop forever

  my ($dev, $ino, $mode, $nlink, $uid, $gid, $rdev, $size,
      $atime, $mtime, $ctime, $blksize, $blocks) = stat($filename);

  if ($mtime != $old_mtime || $size != $old_size) {
     # slurp in entire file and get its sha256 hash
     local $/;
     open(my $fh, "<", $filename) or die "couldn't open $filename: $!\n";
     my $digest = sha256_hex(<$fh>);
     close($fh);

     if ($digest ne $old_digest) {
        printf "changes were made";

        ### $curl upload data details here......................

        $old_digest = $digest; 
        $old_mtime  = $mtime;
        $old_size   = $size
     }
  } else {

        printf "no changes were made";
  };

  sleep 3600; # sleep 1 hour between iterations of the loop
}
```

The problem with this code is that every time when I run this script, it always starts with changes were made even though the file were untouched when saved. What should I change? Should I exclude the time?

Comment: Two options: Assume it didn't change, or store `$old_mtime`, `$old_size` and `$old_digest` somewhere persistent (e.g. to disk).

Comment: is there a way to access the uploaded data, can you retrieve your `$old_mtime`, `$old_size`, and `$old_digest`, and only initialise them yourself if you can not access that data?

Comment: @ikegami any other way? what do u mean it didnt change

Comment: @vanHoesel what do u mean ? i can access my uploaded data, i can read but not write for it. i only want something to happen if the data was changed.

Comment: Re "*what do u mean it didnt change*", Right now, you assume the file has been changed since the last time you ran the program and thus call `curl` whenever you run the program. You could make the opposite assumption.

Comment: @ikegami put the $curl command aside, i just want it to show something when the data is the same / not the same. but everytime i run this script, it always show not same, then same all the way unless i change it

Comment: Yeah, you always compare against 0/0/empty string when you start the program. Either save the correct values between runs, or assume the file didn't change between runs.

Comment: @ikegami any idea how to implement it ?

Comment: Up top you were you store the info. You could use a file.

Comment: @HelpMeAndroidStudio i think what ikegami meant was saving what you already have, the new "time" and stuff into a new file. then read from the file everytime

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Storable](https://perldoc.perl.org/Storable) module to persist your "old" values.

Example:

```perl
#! /usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Storable;
use Digest::SHA qw(sha256_hex);

use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Terse = 1;

my $old;
if (-e 'old') {
  $old = retrieve ('old');
} else {
  $old = {mtime => 0, size => 0, digest => ''};
}
END {
  store $old, 'old';
}

print "$$: old: ", Dumper ($old);

my $filename = 'data.list';

my ($dev, $ino, $mode, $nlink, $uid, $gid, $rdev, $size,
    $atime, $mtime, $ctime, $blksize, $blocks) = stat($filename);

if ($mtime != $old->{mtime} || $size != $old->{size}) {
  # slurp in entire file and get its sha256 hash
  local $/;
  open(my $fh, "<", $filename) or die "couldn't open $filename: $!\n";
  my $digest = sha256_hex(<$fh>);
  close($fh);

  if ($digest ne $old->{digest}) {
    printf "$$: changes were made\n";
    $old->{digest} = $digest; 
    $old->{mtime}  = $mtime;
    $old->{size}   = $size;
    print "$$: new: ", Dumper ($old);
  } else {
    print "$$: no changes were made\n";
  }
} else {
  print "$$: no changes were made\n";
}
```

Initialize the `data.list`:

```
$ echo 1 > data.list
```

Old values are initialized during the first run:

```
$ ./storable.pl
2605: old: {
  'size' => 0,
  'mtime' => 0,
  'digest' => ''
}
2605: changes were made
2605: new: {
  'size' => 2,
  'mtime' => 1624266579,
  'digest' => '4355a46b19d348dc2f57c046f8ef63d4538ebb936000f3c9ee954a27460dd865'
}
```

If you run again the old values are read from the file "old":

```
$ ./storable.pl
2610: old: {
  'size' => 2,
  'mtime' => 1624266579,
  'digest' => '4355a46b19d348dc2f57c046f8ef63d4538ebb936000f3c9ee954a27460dd865'
}
2610: no changes were made
```

But when you change the file, the change gets detected:

```
$ echo 2 > data.list 
$ ./storable.pl
2615: old: {
  'digest' => '4355a46b19d348dc2f57c046f8ef63d4538ebb936000f3c9ee954a27460dd865',
  'mtime' => 1624266579,
  'size' => 2
}
2615: changes were made
2615: new: {
  'digest' => '53c234e5e8472b6ac51c1ae1cab3fe06fad053beb8ebfd8977b010655bfdd3c3',
  'mtime' => 1624266608,
  'size' => 2
}
```

Instead of `sleep` I would use a cron-job.

Comment: hi may i know where this values were stored? just curious coz his post is something that I'm doing too

Comment: Hi ceiving, thanks for this, but it seems that i have to store the value someone and read it again everytime. i cant store values/file on the cloud server

Comment: @WenhanXiao In the file called 'old'. See the `END` block.

Comment: @HelpMeAndroidStudio Every server has a directory to store temporary data. If you are not allowed to use it, you have to store your data in the database. Or you have to create unique constrains in the database to prevent duplicates. In that case you can import always everything and the database will reject the values already imported.